# Persist dynamicly generated html through PHP form via post

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, dynamically-generated

When the application starts, by default there is no `<tr>` or `<td>` inside of the `dynatable`.
I am using javascript to add/remove table rows into the `p_scents` from the client side. This works quite well on the client side.
I am trying to loop through the elements and collect the data into an array for processing in PHP.
When I submit the form, the HTML goes back to default with no data inside the `p_scents` and i am unable to grab the data.

Is there a way to get the HTML elements/values that I created with javascript to persist to the server side? I don't necessarily need the HTML to stay but i need the values in post.

If you need any additional explanations/code I can provide as much as I possibly can, please let me know. I have tried $_POST methods and the code is simply not there. any ideas of what I should be doing in my situation?

**Form on client side:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars('?page_id=133');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<table class="dynatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="p_scents">
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="ts_value" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name="ts_value" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td><td><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

**Form once submitted to server-side:**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo  htmlspecialchars('?page_id=133');?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<table class="dynatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="p_scents">

    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: If you're coming back to the same page, you should use AJAX to submit the form instead, that way you never lose state in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst, as suggested in comments, this is a strong case for ajax, its not then only solution.

1st you will need to give your form elements array syntax names, eg:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="ts_value[]" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description[]" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td><td><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="ts_value[]" class="timestamp_input"/></td><td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description[]" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ></TEXTAREA></td><td><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>
```

Note the square brackets `name="ts_value[]"` without this, you are overwriting the values and will only every receive the last value with that name. Also i changed remScnt to a class, as you cant have duplicate ids.

Then you can easily access the data in php:

```
var_dump($_POST['ts_value']);
```

Rebuilding the form is just a matter of iterating the values:

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['ts_value']) && isset($_POST['ts_description'])):

    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['ts_value']);$i++;):?>

        <tr><td><input type="text" name="ts_value[]" class="timestamp_input" value="<?php echo $_POST['ts_value'][$i];?>" /></td>
        <td><TEXTAREA NAME="ts_description[]" rows="3" cols="30"  style="resize:none;" ><?php echo $_POST['ts_description'][$i];?></TEXTAREA></td><td><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></td></tr>


    <?php endfor;
endif; ?>
```